# Another SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

this is a homework question regarding SQL.  The two tables being used are as follows, the data in them is irrelevant.

```
Restaurants

    RNum | RestaurantName | HQLocation
```

and the orders table:

```
Orders

    CNum | DNum | RNum | Quant | Price
```

The issue I'm having is that I cannot figure out how to specify Restaurants that have their only orders from customer C200. The query is worded as such:

"Name the restaurants whose only order(s) came from customer C200."

I have tried to solve this a bunch of different ways and will post two that I thought will work, though neither did as the answer table should only involve one record.

Here is my first try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT R.RestaurantName
FROM Orders AS O, Restaurants AS R
WHERE (O.RNum = R.RNum)
AND (O.CNum = 'C200')
```

and here is another:

```
SELECT DISTINCT R.RestaurantName
FROM Restaurants AS R
WHERE EXISTS
              (SELECT *
               FROM Orders AS O
               WHERE (O.RNum = R.RNum)
               AND (O.Rnum = 'C200'))
```

I'm having a lot of trouble excluding all the other possibilities and all of my queries keep returning more than one record.  Is there a way using nested queries (no joins) to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

`SELECT * FROM Restaurants WHERE RNum IN (SELECT RNum FROM Orders GROUP BY RNum HAVING Sum(IIf([CNum]<>'C200',1,0))=0);`

Using data from your other thread, 3 restaurants meet the criteria.

Comment: that worked, I would like to know exactly what the if statement is doing though, mainly the ",1,0" portion of it, thanks again @June7

Comment: The aggregate Sum is conditionally adding 1 for each record that is not a C200 and adding 0 for each C200. This means if the Sum result is 0 for a restaurant there are only C200 for that restaurant.

Answer (score 1):

A tiny improvement from June7's answer:

```
SELECT RestaurantName FROM Restaurants WHERE RNum IN 
(SELECT RNum FROM Orders GROUP BY RNum HAVING Sum(IIf([CNum]<>'C200',1,0))=0);
```

Answer (score 0):

May this sql will work as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RestaurantName 
FROM Restaurants 
WHERE RNum IN 
(
    SELECT RNum 
    FROM Orders 
    WHERE CNum = "C200"
)
```

Comment: Does not exclude restaurants who had orders from C200 as well as other customers.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
select distinct r.RestaurantName from Restaurants as r
inner join Orders as o ON o.RNum = r.RNum
where o.CNum='c200';
```